# WordPress - MySQL Auto Increment User ID

Tags: mysql, wordpress, auto-increment, sql-insert

I am looking to run two instances of `WordPress` which sync on a regular basis.

The way I am going to do this is to have the auto increment offset on each different.

So for example on instance one the user IDs would be `1,3,5,7` etc. And on instance two the user IDs would be `2,4,6,8` etc.

Within `WordPress` there is the user function `wp_insert_user` which I would like to add a filter to for the database insert of a new user.

The issue is I cannot see a filter directly before or relating to the insert. So I am stuck on how I would achieve this.

The function is found in `wp-includes\user.php` file on line 1856 and within that on line 2060 is the insert statement for a new user:

```
$wpdb->insert( $wpdb->users, $data + compact( 'user_login' ) );
$user_id = (int) $wpdb->insert_id;
```

Could someone assist please? I just need pointing in the right direction as like I say I am not sure of the direction I need to take but want to ensure that the code I use is per the `WordPress framework`.

Comment: Thanks Emil; are these settings just database wide - and not MySQL wide? As I don't want other databases on the same server being set to the new value.

Answer (score 1):

Configure this in MySQL directly. I assume you are going to sync all tables, in which case you might want to always increment by two. You can change the global auto_increment interval with [auto_increment_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment):

```
SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment=2;
```

Then configure each instance to have a different `auto_increment_offset`:

```
SET GLOBAL auto_increment_offset=1;
SET GLOBAL auto_increment_offset=2;
```